# Multiple Spring JPA relationships between 2 entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities, one for a taskList and the other for users. The users can create tasks for themselves or their friends, so in the Tasks entity I have different columns referencing the `User` entity, one for `createdBy` another for `createdFor` and a last one for `modifiedBy`.
In the `tasks` entity I made the following `@ManyToOne` JPA relationships:

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", nullable = false,
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_for", nullable = false,
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User createdFor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by", nullable = false,
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User modifiedBy;
```

But I am not sure how to do the linking in the `Users` side, I had the following `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdFor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> taskList;
```

But I am not sure how to proceed with the other relationships as I don't really need a `taskList` for the tasks that a user created, or what tasks did he modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to map all things in an Entity , and also do not need to configure every relationships as bi-directional.

So if you really do not need to access the `Tasks` that are created and modified from a given `User` , just ignore them and do not map them in `User`.

It is perfectly valid to configure a relationship as unidirectional. Your existing codes should already work perfectly.